# Why does MySQL keep picking the "is NULL" column index over the "JOIN" column index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

There are many questions already answered on stackoverflow that discuss how SQL chooses an index, by using various statistics on the tables and estimating how helpful each index will be. I'm hoping that with a more specific question someone might be able to shed light on exactly how that applies to my situation.

The query is along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
  on TableB.data_id = TableA.data_id
  and TableB.customer_id is NULL
WHERE TableB.id is NULL
```

There is an index on `TableB.id` and `TableB.customer_id`. The MySQL database keeps choosing to use the index on `TableB.customer_id`. This causes the query to run painfully slowly, whereas if I force it to use the index on `TableB.id`, it is fast.

`TableA` and `TableB` both have 100,000 - 1,000,000 rows and matches on many of them. `TableB.customer_id` is almost all NULL.

Is there a specific reason why MySQL would choose the index on `customer_id` in this case?

Is there something about the `is NULL` clause vs the `= TableA.id` clause that makes it think this would be more useful?

I would have thought that it would choose the index on `id` since that is the column being compared to another table and it is the column that needs a specific value, rather than just NULL vs. NOT NULL.

Comment: if the majority of your values is just null - the index has a "bad cardinality", because it is build out of only few unique values and much equal values (null). - Why index that column at all?

Comment: For your query (a `left join`), that index makes no sense. Either your "along the lines of" was too simplified, or you missed some details (maybe a foreign key or a `where`-condition for `B`). Please add the execution plan (the output of `explain select * ...`) to your question and make sure that you are using the correct query.

Comment: @dognose Good question. Down the line, it may not be mostly NULL. But it's worth thinking about whether to remove the index altogether.

Comment: @Solarflare I have edited the question so that the query includes a where condition and more closely matches the full query. I don't see what difference it makes though.

Comment: You mentioned `TableA.customer_id is almost all NULL`. In your Query, You are looking for `and TableB.customer_id is NULL` in your query. If condition is with `TableA.customer_id` then you can write it in where clause to avoid index scan issue.

Comment: @JERRY Sorry, I had a typo, which I will now correct. There is only `TableB.customer_id`

Comment: Well, with and without `where` are two completely different queries. Try it without `where`; it will not take that "wrong" index, so it makes it impossible for us to answer why it takes the wrong index. MySQL actually tells you why it takes a particular execution plan: in the execution plan. That is why I asked for it, so we don't have to guess. Please add the output of `explain format=json select ...` for your query with and without forcing the index (for MySQL 5.5: just `explain select...`). You can obfuscate names, but please don't remove anything (as you may not know if it's relevant).

Answer (score 0):

The index on `TableB.id` is irrelevant to

```
 on TableB.data_id = TableA.data_id
and TableB.customer_id is NULL
```

Instead, have this composite index:

```
INDEX(data_id, customer_id)
```